# Anchors/coordinates inside a node's text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, line-spacing

## The plot

Using tikz, I have a main node containing several (three) lines of text, and three "legend" nodes that point to them.

If I use a `rectangle` node, then I can't access the positions of the individual lines, so I can only attach my legends to the main node itself, and can't vertically align them with their respective line:

[image: A rectangle node containing three lines with a unique legend for the whole node.]

If I use a `matrix` node, with each line in an individual cell, then the inter-line spacing is wrong. I could add `row sep=42pt`, but I don't know which value to put in place of 42:

[image: A matrix node with a cell for each line, and a legend for each line, the lines are stuck together without any vertical spacing.]

As a last ressort, I added an invisible rule with a height of `\baselineskip` to each line (cell) except the first one, which seems to give a result identical to the rectangular node, except I can access the position of individual lines:

[image: A matrix node with a cell for each line, and a legend for each line, the vertical spacing is the same as in the rectangle node.]

However, this won't work well if the line contains equations or anything that makes it higher than a regular line. [This TeX.sx answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74154/5699) shows that the inter-line space in that case is given by `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`, but I woul really fancy the idea of re-implementing that using tikz -- I wouldn't even know where to start I must admit.

## The question

Is there any simpler/more robust way to access each individual line in a tikz `node` as if the line was a rectangle node?

## The code

### Preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\def\legendlines#1#2{
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
  \draw (#2.north west) -- (#2.south west);
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,align=center},
  mylegend/.style={align=left, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
}
```

### Rectangle node

```
% I can't access the position of each line using a rectangle node
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three};
  \node[mylegend, xshift=1cm, at=(N123.east), anchor=west] (L123) {Legend 1\\Legend 2\\Legend 3};
  \legendlines{N123}{L123}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Matrix node

```
% Using a matrix, the inter-line space is wrong. I can add row sep=42pt, but I don't know what is the correct value.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Invisible rule

```
% Using an invisible rule
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line two\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Epilogue

```
\end{document}
```

### Whole code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\def\legendlines#1#2{
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
  \draw (#2.north west) -- (#2.south west);
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,align=center},
  mylegend/.style={align=left, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
}

% I can't access the position of each line using a rectangle node
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three};
  \node[mylegend, xshift=1cm, at=(N123.east), anchor=west] (L123) {Legend 1\\Legend 2\\Legend 3};
  \legendlines{N123}{L123}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using a matrix, the inter-line space is wrong. I can add row sep=42pt, but I don't know what is the correct value.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using an invisible rule
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line two\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put the text in a `\subnode` command from the experimental `tikzmark` package, would that be an acceptable solution?  Then each line could be treated as a separate node while the line positioning and spacing are set by the container node.

Comment: I forgot to say I tried manually putting a `\tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (Line1) {};}` at the end of each line, but that resulted in coordinates that were shifted from where they should have been. Hopefully `tikzmark` will give a better result than this brutal approach :) I don't have it installed, so I'll test that later. I also tried using multipart nodes, with the same inter-line spacing problems that the matrix solution has, only more difficult to solve. Please do post `\subnode` as a solution if you can do a quick check that it works.

Comment: Nesting tikzpictures is fraught with dangers.  Subnodes get round this by not being tikzpictures but emulating the bare minimum.  It's late for me now so I won't get a chance to try it out before tomorrow - if no-one beats me to it!

Comment: In the meantime, you can see an example at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84457/86

Comment: Do you need to replicate the rectangle node exactly? Otherwise `row sep=1ex` seems sufficient for the matrix.

Comment: @percusse: I don't *need* to replicate the rectangle node exactly, it's just I try to avoid guessing values when sensible defaults are provided by another method (in this case, using a rectangle node). Also, this is the kind of little inexactitude that easily breaks the consistency of the diagram :) .

Comment: Incidentally, the divided code looks very nice but is a pain to cut-and-paste.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Indeed, I didn't think about that. I added the code as a single chunk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using `\subnode` from the experimental `tikzmark` package.  "Experimental" in this case means "not yet on CTAN": you need to download it from the [TeX-SX Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) site.  Download the file `tikzmark.dtx` and run `tex tikzmark.dtx` (if you run `latex` or `pdflatex` it will complain of a missing file - ignore that).  Put the resulting files somewhere that `tex` can find them.

Here's your code with the `\subnode` last.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86456/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix,tikzmark}
\def\legendlines#1#2{
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
  \draw (#2.north west) -- (#2.south west);
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,align=center},
  mylegend/.style={align=left, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
}
% I can't access the position of each line using a rectangle node
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three};
  \node[mylegend, xshift=1cm, at=(N123.east), anchor=west] (L123) {Legend 1\\Legend 2\\Legend 3};
  \legendlines{N123}{L123}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using a matrix, the inter-line space is wrong. I can add row sep=42pt, but I don't know what is the correct value.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using an invisible rule
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, matrix, matrix of nodes, nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line two\\\rule{0cm}{\baselineskip}Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (N123) {\subnode{mynode-1}{Node line one}\\\subnode{mynode-2}{Node line two}\\\subnode{mynode-3}{Node line three}};
  \coordinate (L123) at=(N123.east);
  \foreach \k in {1,2,3} {
  \node[mylegend,xshift=\k cm,anchor=base west] (L\k) at (mynode-\k.base -| L123) {Legend \k};
  \legendlines{mynode-\k.mid west -| N123.mid east}{L\k}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: subnode division of node]

Answer (score 11):

The matrix is *imho* the best solution. If you don't want all lines crampled, why did you put `node={inner sep=0pt}`? Removing this option gives:

[image: Result]

As the OP noted in a comment, the above solution produces more padding than the standard rectangle solution. This can be avoided by giving `inner sep=0pt` to the outer matrix node, and `inner sep=3.333pt` (which is the default inner sep) to each of the inner nodes (cells).
There is a MWE which includes the rectangle for comparison:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\def\legendlines#1#2{
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
  \draw (#2.north west) -- (#2.south west);
}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={draw,fill=blue!30,align=center},
  mylegend/.style={align=left, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
}

% Using a matrix, the inter-line space is wrong. I can add row sep=42pt, but I don't know what is the correct value.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode, inner sep=0pt, matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=3.33pt}] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three\\};
  % Coordinates along the east side of N123
  \coordinate (N1east) at (N123-1-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N2east) at (N123-2-1.east -| N123.east);
  \coordinate (N3east) at (N123-3-1.east -| N123.east);
  % Legend texts
  \node[mylegend, right=1.0cm of N1east] (L1) {Legend 1};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.2cm of N2east] (L2) {Legend 2};
  \node[mylegend, right=1.4cm of N3east] (L3) {Legend 3};
  % Legend lines
  \legendlines{N1east}{L1}
  \legendlines{N2east}{L2}
  \legendlines{N3east}{L3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[mynode] (N123) {Node line one\\Node line two\\Node line three};
  \node[mylegend, xshift=1cm, at=(N123.east), anchor=west] (L123) {Legend 1\\Legend 2\\Legend 3};
  \legendlines{N123}{L123}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: If you don't put `node={inner sep=0pt}`, then you get some extra space on the sides and bottom/top: The matrix node has its own `inner sep`, that it puts around the cells, and if the cells themeselves have some inner sep, it's doubled. If you use `inner sep=0pt` on the matrix itself, but leave the nodes alone, then you'll have double space between nodes (`inner sep` of the upper node, and `inner sep` of the lower node), but only a single `inner sep` space between the text and the border.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below with [remember picture] seems simpler and more flexible but need two compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

\node[text width=5cm,draw](tab){ ligne 1\tikz \coordinate(l1); \\
ligne 2 plus longue\tikz \coordinate(l2); \\
~\\
ligne 4\tikz \coordinate(l4); };

\draw[-|] (l1-|tab.east) -- ++(2,0) node[right]{legende 1};
\draw [-|](l2-|tab.east) -- ++(2.5,0) node[right]{legende 2};
\draw [-|](l4-|tab.east) -- ++(3,0) node[right]{legende 3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this suffers from the "nested tikzpicture" problem.  Try putting, say, `baseline=15pt` on the *outer* `tikzpicture` and see what happens.  The `\subnode` command was written to get round this issue (it works on the same underlying principle).

Comment: I had tried something similar, but the coordinates ended up in weird places. That's because I use beamer and overlays, so for the `[remember picture]` to stabilize, I need 3, 4 or even 5 compilations -- and I gave up before reaching that number. `\subnode` needs just as many compilations (since it relies on `[remember picture]` just like your `\coordinate`s), but avoids some of the problems caused by nested `tikzpicture`s, like Andrew said.